# my question is related to probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There are $16$ white socks, $12$ black socks, and $8$ blue socks in a dark room. You are allowed to enter the room once; so then how many socks do you need to take to be sure to get two matching pairs.

The answer is $6$. But I realy don't know the formula how to solve it. Please help me in this with a pretty explanation.

Comment: Easier, I think, to look for the largest "failed" selection.  In this case, you could take, for example, $(3,1,1)$.  Then you'd get a white pair, but no other matches.  If you draw at least $6$ then either two colors are chosen at least  twice, or one color is chosen at least  four times and either way you win.

Answer (score 3):

It may be helpful to first think about how many socks you would need to get to be sure to have at least 1 pair. Since there are three different colors, getting 3 socks is not enough, since you could get 1 sock from each color. However, once you have 1 sock of each color, then picking a fourth sock is guaranteed to create a pair. So, it takes 4 socks to be sure to have a pair.

Ok, but once you have 1 pair, you can set that aside, and you are (worst case) left with 2 socks of different colors, which means the 5th spck can be of the third color ... But then the sixth sock will have to create a pair again. So, it takes 6 socks to be sure to have 2 pairs.

And it will continue like this: it takes 8 socks to be sure to have 3 pairs, 10 for 4, etc. ... Except that at some point you run out of socks of certain colors, so then things change again. Indeed, if you pick 36 socks, you are sure to have 18 pairs!